Max and Transpose in the Probability of a Union
If I have the code that gives the probability of the sum in general
p[un[x_, y__]] := p[un[x]] + p[un[y]] - p[in[un@x, un@y]];
un[un[x__]] := un[x];
un[in[x__]] := in[x];
in[un[x__]] := un[x];
in[x_, un[z_, y__]] := un[in[un@x, un@z], in[un@x, un@y]];
in[in[x__]] := in[x];
in[in[x__], in[y__]] := in @@ Intersection[{x, y}]

I have the following two vectors as a simple example
A1 = {1, 2, 0, 3, 5};
A2 = {3, 1, 0, 4, 1};

I want to apply the Probability of a union as follows
p[un[A1, A2]] /. un[x_] :> x /. 
 in[un@x_, un@y_] :> Max /@ Transpose[{x, y}]

 p[{1, 2, 0, 3, 5}] + p[{3, 1, 0, 4, 1}]-p[in[{1, 2, 0, 3, 5}, {3, 1, 0, 4, 1}]]

But I have a problem with the Max function (Max /@ Transpose[{x, y}]) not giving the desired result
p[in[{1, 2, 0, 3, 5}, {3, 1, 0, 4, 1}]]=p[{3,2,0,4,5}]

Note that
Max /@ Transpose[{A1, A2}]={3,2,0,4,5}

I am looking for a solution that applies the code globally to vectors A1,...,An.
Please help me, with thanks and respect.

Your related post 305467 and this has the general gist. A key concept hampering you in both questions is that you do not need a separate variable for every vector and distribution.  For this problem List and the concepts of Functional Programming are what you are missing for cases up to $n$.
For the generalised form of union probability
\begin{align}
P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) - \sum_{i <j}P(A_i \cap A_j) + \cdots + (-1)^{n+1}P(\cap_{i=1}^nA_i).
\end{align}
You only need two functions; probability of an event and the probability of the intersection of events. Lets take each in turn.
With events
events = {
   {2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1}
   , {3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1}
   , {2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2}
   };

and distributions
distributions = {
   EmpiricalDistribution[{0.05, 0.10, 0.25, 0.60} -> {0, 1, 2, 3}]
   , EmpiricalDistribution[{0.10, 0.30, 0.60} -> {0, 1, 2}]
   , EmpiricalDistribution[{0.10, 0.90} -> {0, 1}]
   , EmpiricalDistribution[{0.10, 0.90} -> {0, 1}]
   , EmpiricalDistribution[{0.10, 0.90} -> {0, 1}]
   , EmpiricalDistribution[{0.05, 0.25, 0.70} -> {0, 1, 2}]
   };

You provided your definition of the probability of an event in your related question.  I created a function prob from that definition with vector your event and dists the related list of distributions.
prob[vector_, dists_] :=
 Product[
  Apply[Probability[\[FormalX] >= #1, \[FormalX] \[Distributed] #2] &]@i
  , {i, Transpose[{vector, dists}]}
 ]

This can be used for the terms of the first sum.
Apply[prob] /@ Map[Append[{#}, distributions ] &, events]


{0.43605, 0.3078, 0.433755}


The intersection formula was also defined from which I created probIntersect. It takes the list of events (vectors) to intersect and the related distributions (dists).
probIntersect[vectors_, dists_] := prob[Max /@ Transpose[vectors], dists]

This can be used for terms of the second sum. For example the intersection of the first and second event or the intersection of all three events.
probIntersect[events[[{1, 2}]], distributions]


0.27702


probIntersect[events[[{1, 2, 3}]], distributions]


0.20412


Now for the interesting part.  How can the second sum be constructed with probIntersect?  There are a few challenges. The number of events is not known ahead of time so Sum's iterator sequence cannot be hard coded. The unknown number of iteration symbols are needed for each intersection set.  These issues are solved by the iterators function.
iterators[numEvents_Integer, numIters_Integer] :=
 Module[{syms, iter = ConstantArray[Null, numIters]}
  , syms = Array[Unique["i" <> ToString@#] &, numIters] 
  ; iter[[1]] = {syms[[1]], 1, numEvents - (numIters - 1)}
  ; (iter[[#]] = {syms[[#]], syms[[# - 1]] + 1, numEvents}) & /@ Range[2, numIters]
  ; iter
  ]

iterators generates the symbols and required sequence of indices needed for an intersection term of the second sum.  In the example case the pair-wise iterator sequence is
iterators[3, 2]


{{i170, 1, 2}, {i271, 1 + i170, 3}}


All these items are brought together in the probUnion function. This takes the event vectors (vects), the related distributions (dists), the probability function (probFunc), and the intersection function (intersectFunc).
probUnion[vects_?MatrixQ, dists_, probFunc_, intersectFunc_] :=
 Module[
  {probs = ConstantArray[Null, Length@vects]
   , numIters = Length@vects
   , unionIters}
  , probs[[1]] = Apply[probFunc] /@ Map[Append[{#}, dists] &, vects]
  ; probs[[2 ;; numIters]] =
   Sum[
      intersectFunc[vects[[#]] & /@ #[[All, 1]], dists]
      , Evaluate[Sequence @@ #]
      ] & /@ Map[iterators[numIters, #] &, Range[2, numIters]]
  ; Plus @@ Flatten[Power[-1, Range[0, numIters - 1]] probs]
  ]

For the example
probUnion[events, distributions, prob, probIntersect]


0.611415


Should there be other cases with different definitions for probability and intersection then those functions can be passed instead.
Hope this helps.

A wonderful and general answer...there is a simple typo “sym=syms”. Thank you very much. This answer helped me.

@Emadkareem Ah - I see it too and fixed it.
